# Difference between electrostatic and magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, magnetic-fields

[image]

In this, F (the force set by the field) is perpendicular to the speed of the particle. In which case does F change the absolute value of V? Why or why not?

Comment: Please see [our homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/715/7433). We expect homework and homework-like problems to have some effort put into them, and deal with conceptual issues. If you edit your question to explain (1) What you have tried, (2) the concept you have trouble with, and (3) your level of understanding, I'll be happy to reopen this. (Flag this message for ♦ attention with a custom message, or reply to me in the comments with `@Manishearth` to notify me)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magnetic field never does any work , as it acts perpendicular to the velocity and thus doesn't change Kinetic energy , however electric field is able to change the direction as well as magnitude of velocity.

Hence answer is electric field.

Answer (score 0):

The direction of the electric force on a charged particle is constant, independent of the direction the charge is moving in. The magnetic force on the other hand is always at right angles to the direction the charge is moving in.